# Y-axis values don't match the continuous values of data R

Tags: r, ggplot2, yaxis

I have used the same code for similar datasets but for some reason, it is not working for this one.

This is roughly what I get. (I hid the categorical variable names)

[image]

This is the code that I have been using:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2) 

df%>%
  arrange(desc(round), measure) %>%
  mutate(concept = factor(concept, unique(concept))) %>%
  ggplot() +aes(x=concept, y=measure, fill=round)+
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(name="round", values = c("purple", "red")) +
  coord_flip()+ 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=upper, ymin=lower),position=position_dodge(.9))
```

Here is a sample df

```
    structure(list(concept = c("ball", "camel", "wind", 
    "dog", "happy", "script", "condensation", "Marxism"), 
        measure = c(2.45, 3.2, 3.91, 3.94, 4.31, 3.63, 4.54, 4.55), upper = c(6.46, 
        6.11, 7.23, 7.9, 9.17, 11.23, 11.32, 15.3), lower = c(1.56, 
        0.79, 1.45, 1.02, 1.65, 1.31, 1.64, 3.07), round = c("One", 
        "Two", "Two", "Two", "Two", "Two", "Two", 
        "Two")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi Imdinios. Could you clarify your question? What do you mean by "Y-axis values don't match the continuous values of data"?

Comment: You say this is a sample of `df` - is the plot you show from this sample, or from your whole data? My best guess is that your real data has more rows, with multiple rows for each `concept`. Then the bars, by default, will be stacked on top of each other, adding their `measure` values. But the `arrange` and `unique(concept)` you have are ordering the concepts by the *max* value rather than by the *sum* - which is what your plot is showing.

Comment: @stefan Yes, of course. So for example, the value for one variable is 6.67, the graph is showing that as 9.5 because the axis labels are wrong when it should theoretically only go from 0-10 if the largest value is 9.5.

Comment: @imdinos I don't understand. Which variable are you referring to should be 6.67? Your sample `df` has neither 6.67 nor 9.5. You also have `upper` values greater than 10. The values on the plot using your ggplot code matches the values in your sample df. You can add something like `geom_text(aes(label = upper, y = upper)) + scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1:15, minor_breaks = NULL)` to make it easier to double check.